# Автоматический просмотр видео Python+Selenium

Tags: python, python-3.x, selenium-webdriver

Есть задача (для себя) написать бот для просмотра видео на Перископе.

Алгоритм:

1. Вставляешь ссылку на трансляцию и даём значение переменной n = количество выполнений пунктов 3 и 4.
2. Идёт проверка каждые "n" секунд наличие текста на сайте, если текст на сайте есть переходим к 3 пункту.
3. Скрипт запускает на просмотр видео и одновременно пингует на наличие на сайте текста о завершение трансляции, после завершения трансляции, переходим к 4 пункту.

Но тут возникают ошибки (основная запись):

**ConnectionRefusedError: [WinError 10061] Подключение не установлено, т.к. конечный компьютер отверг запрос на подключение**

Думал что поможет исправить проблему увелечение интервала запросов на сайт, ставил ожидание 120 сек., не помогло.

Сам код программы:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.common.exceptions import NoSuchElementException
import time

global n
n = 0
global i
i = 0

def getProfile():
    profile = webdriver.FirefoxProfile()
    profile.set_preference("browser.privatebrowsing.autostart", True)
    return profile

def work(driver):
    time.sleep(120)
    try:
        driver.find_element_by_id('video_swf_0')
    except NoSuchElementException:
        print('Такого элемента на сайте существует!')
        driver.close()
        time.sleep(120)
        work(driver)
    else:
        print('Такой элемент на сайте существует!')
        driver.close()
        time.sleep(120)
        works(driver)

def works(driver):
    while (i<=n):
        time.sleep(120)
        driver = webdriver.Firefox(firefox_profile=getProfile())
        driver.implicitly_wait(5) # seconds
        driver.get(url_t)
        time.sleep(120)
        try:
            driver.find_element_by_id('video_swf_0')
        except NoSuchElementException:
            print('Такого элемента на сайте существует!')
            driver.close()
            time.sleep(120)
            works(driver)
        else:
            print('Такой элемент на сайте существует!')
            i = i + 1
            time.sleep(120)
            works_c(driver)

def works_c(driver):
    time.sleep(120)
    driver.implicitly_wait(5)
    driver.get(url_t)
    try:
        driver.find_element_by_id('video_swf_0')
    except NoSuchElementException:
        driver.close()
        time.sleep(120)
        works(driver)
    else:
        time.sleep(120)
        works_c(driver)  

def main():
    url_t = input("Введи ссылку на трансляцию: ")
    n = int(input("Введи количество просмотров трансляции: "))
    driver = webdriver.Firefox(firefox_profile=getProfile())
    driver.implicitly_wait(5) # seconds
    driver.get(url_t)
    time.sleep(5)
    work(driver)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Comment: код сервера при этом какой? WinError 10061 это у питона, а у сервера который отдавал страницу ответ 405 ?

Comment: browser.privatebrowsing.autostart если не ставить приватный, то ошибка есть?

Comment: Проверил код, у меня работает. Проверте, работает ли ссылка в обычном браузере.

Comment: Пример урла бы получить

Comment: Я бы не морочился с поиском контента на сайте, а сразу бы слал команды воспроизведения с "мультимедиа клавиш".

Answer (score 1):

На сколько я помню, thread.sleep принимает значение в миллисекундах. Тоесть, чтобы ожидать 120 секунд надо прописать 120000. НО принудительное ожидание это не правильно!
Правильнее сделать примерно так:

```
timeout = 120
while driver.find_element_by_id('video_swf_0') == null:
    if timeout > 0:
        thread.sleep(1000)
        timeout = timeout - 1
    else: 
        break;
```